# Matrix Multiplication Rules

Tags: linear-algebra

Unfortunately I cannot post up the full question, but I need this little idea (whether its true or false to answer another question)

Let's say we have $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A,B$ be matrices with $B$ being symmetric. Then if

$v^tA^tBw = v^tBAw$

Is there a rule that can help me argue that $A^tB = BA$?  $(*)$

Somehow if I can show this then this means,

$A^tB^t = BA$ iff $(BA)^t = BA$. Hence $BA$ is symmetric.

[Side note: I have used $v^t$ to denote the transpose]. Again sorry I cannot give more context I cannot post up the question due to reasons. So my main point is $(*)$

Comment: The following statement is true:
$$\forall v,w\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}\left(v^TA^TBw=v^TBAw\right)\implies A^TB=BA.$$ The following assertion is false: $$\forall v,w\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}\left(v^TA^TBw=v^TBAw\implies A^TB=BA\right).$$ I can't understand which one you mean.

Comment: I guess the one above, exactly what the user blst is saying below is my statement. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Bobby so are you saying that $v^tA^tBw = v^tBAw$ holds for *some particular choice* of $v,w$, or that $v^tA^tBw = v^tBAw$ holds for *any choice* of $v,w$?

Comment: I'm saying the statement holds for any choice of $v,w$ and would this mean $A^tB = BA$?

Comment: @Bobby yes, it would.  In general, if $v^T C w = v^T D w$ for every $v,w$, then $C = D$.  To see why, let $v,w$ be the standard basis vectors.

Comment: Sorry I don't see it, how does setting v, w be the standard basis vectors show this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to show $A^TB^T = BA \iff (BA)^T = BA$: I think you would be able to get by with the general statement
$$
(AB)^T = B^TA^T
$$
which holds for any matrices $A,B$.  Here's a [proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Transpose_of_Matrix_Product).

Comment: That was not the OP's question.

Comment: @PeterPatzt read: "*Somehow if I can show this then this means...*"

Comment: this meaning the above statement not $(AB)^T=A^TB^T$.

Comment: Thank you Onom for the reply, but I wanted to show $(*)$

Comment: @PeterPatzt Right, which means he's trying to use his statement (which the first part of the question is indeed about) to prove that $A^TB^T = BA \iff (BA)^T = BA$.  This is silly, since there's an easier way to do it.

Comment: Ok, then nevermind. I have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Well, there was the question that was asked, and there was the question that really needed to be answered.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure on your wording, but assuming you mean $v^tA^tBw = v^tBAw$ holds for all $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and you want to prove that $A^tB=BA$, then you can write $v^tA^tBw = v^tBAw$ as $v^tC=v^tD$, where $C=A^tBw,D=BAw$. Thus we see that $C$ has to equal $D$. Now repeat this process.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. But sorry to ask, why exactly $C = D$? I understand up to $v^tC = v^tD$ bit but why can we conclude $C = D$ after this?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that since, If $AB=AC$ then $B=C$ iff $A$ is invertible

Comment: Actually, since you wrote $v^tA^tBw = v^tBAw$ *for all* $v,w$ (especially for the $n$ linearly independent basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$) it is true. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate your help. Thank you.